# Oracle Reports - Setting Variable from Database

Tags: database, oracle, variables, report

I'm trying to figure out how to assign my variables values pulled from a table in my database in Oracle Reports. This code lies in one of my user parameters:

```
function Project_idValidTrigger return boolean is
begin
:project_id := 'BMDSA';
SELECT VALUE into project_id from WOS_REPORT_PARAM where parameter = 'PROJECT_ID'and SEQUENCE_NUM := sequenceNum;

return (TRUE);
end;
```

The table in the database consists of 4 columns: SEQUENCE_NUM, SYS_DATE, VALUE, PARAMETER.

What I am trying to do is set my user parameter "Project_ID" with a value from my table that has the specified parameter and sequenceNum, sequenceNum being provided by another user parameter.

Hopefully I'm conveying what I need to do properly, Oracle Reports and SQL are still very new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is what you are looking for (considering `project_id` and `sequenceNum` are your report parameters -

```
function Project_idValidTrigger return boolean is
begin

 :project_id := 'BMDSA'; 

  SELECT VALUE 
    INTO :project_id   --gets value into the parameter
    FROM WOS_REPORT_PARAM 
   WHERE parameter = 'PROJECT_ID'
     AND SEQUENCE_NUM = :sequenceNum;  --uses the parameter value in the AND clause

  return (TRUE);
end;
```

Points to remember - `:=` is used for assignment, so in short it cannot be used in a `SQL` query. The report parameters act as bind variables inside the function denoted by `:` operator before the parameter name.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking to do. I'm learning as I go, and the ':=' and ':' were very confusing to me.